# Phonegap ios app documents ajax status 404

Tags: ajax, cordova, http-status-code-404, ios9, status

Phonegap ajax return status 404 in ios9, when i try ios app documents file.
My Code,

```
 $.ajax({
url: external_file_dir + 'templates/index.htm',
success: function (adata) {
 $('body').append(adata.substring(adata.indexOf('<body>') + 6, adata.indexOf('</body>')));
 $('head').append(adata.substring(adata.indexOf('<head>') + 6, adata.indexOf('</head>')));
 },
error: function (objects) {
 alert("responseText : " + objects.responseText);
 alert("status : " + objects.status);
 alert("statusText : " + objects.statusText);
} 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in IOS URL to app documents is case sensitive, if i give correct file name with case sensitive it will be work.